# Finding the surface area revolved around the x-axis.

Tags: calculus

More specifically I have a problem that states:
Let $\Omega$ be the region bounded by the function $Y=x^3$ and the x-axis for $0 \le x\le1$  .This region is revolved about the x-axis. Find the surface area of the solid formed.

I got $\frac{\pi}{27}$ but that doesnt seem to be answer choice.

Comment: How did you calculate the surface area to get $\pi/27$?

Comment: @MikePierce  I did the integral from 0 to 1 of 2pi * f(x) * sqrt(1+(f'(x))^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formula:

$$\text{S}_x=2\pi\int_a^bf(x)\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x$$

So we get, when $f(x)=x^3$, $a=0$ and $b=1$:

$$\text{S}_x=2\pi\int_0^1x^3\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^3\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=2\pi\int_0^1x^3\sqrt{1+9x^4}\space\text{d}x$$

Because $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^3\right)=3x^2$.

Now, use a substitution $u=1+9x^4$ and $\text{d}u=36x^3\space\text{d}x$:

$$\text{S}_x=\frac{\pi}{18}\int_1^{10}\sqrt{u}\space\text{d}u=\frac{\pi\left(10\sqrt{10}-1\right)}{27}\approx3.563121852013749$$

Comment: If you substitute $u=1+9x^4$ and the old lower was $0$ then we get for the new lower bound $u=1+9\cdot0^4=1$ and the old upper was $1$ then we get for the new upper bound $u=1+9\cdot1^4=10$

Comment: yes, of course thank you!

Comment: @MasterExploder You're welcome I'm glad that I could help